# How to write groovy Script in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
I am new to Jmeter and Related Stuff.
Just Finished with Login Request and Response through Selenium WebDriver Sampler(using Java Script) .
Screen shot is also attached with this post.
All working  Well.
Now i go through some articles ,they stress on using groovy script(under JSR223 Sampler) but i am not able to figure out how to convert this same Javascript(WDS sampler) in Groovy(JSR223 sampler) runnable Script.I will be very thankful for any Kind of help in this direction.
 Thanks

groovy(Groovy 2.4.15/Groovy Scripting Engine 2.0) is already displayed in my JSR223 Sampler [i m using apache-jmeter-5.0 ] i run hello world program its working fine..further i have no idea abt how to play with groovy script.
Below is my code in Javascipt(selenium WDS)

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.log.info("Maximo Application ---- Sample started");
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); 
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);
var conditions=org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
var selenium_keys=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.Keys);
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
//-----------------------------Login in Application---------------------------------------------

WDS.browser.get('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/maximo/webclient/login/login.jsp'); //opens website  
WDS.log.info("Maximo Application ---- Username and Password dynamicly picked from C:/user.csv ");

//UserName
var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('username'));  
WDS.log.info("Maximo Application ---- Username "+'${username}');
userName.click(); 
userName.sendKeys('${username}'); 
//Password
var password=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("password"));
password.click();
WDS.log.info("Maximo Application ---- password "+'${password}');
password.clear();
password.sendKeys('${password}');
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("loginbutton")).click();
WDS.log.info("Maximo Application ---- Logged by USER Name--- "+ '${username}');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

I really Wann to switch on groovy as all coming scenarios are going to be complex

[WDS_javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSL6h.png)

Answer (score 0):

i could give you the guidance about your code.

in general, even when you are using javascript in jmeter - you are calling java methods.

groovy will do the same but in syntax it's closer to java.

so:

- declare variables with `def` instead of `var`
- change `JavaImporter(XYZ)` to `import XYZ` at the beginning of script
- remove all java imported variables as they not needed. such as `support_ui`

just an example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*; //need .* to import all classes from package
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait; //import exact class

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //code remains the same
//var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //moved to import
//var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //moved to import
def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000); //removed `support_ui.`

def userName = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('username')); //removed `pkg.`
```

and finally just learn java & groovy

Comment: Thanks dagett ,   for your valuable response.   but still i m not able to understand how to get userid and password element from HTML  in short how to write groovy compatible code for  var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('username'));

Comment: This line in my answer.